# Is it possible to get the index of a for-each loop in Java

Tags: java

Given the code below, is it possible to remove the index of `p` from the properties list using this style of for loop in Java?

```
List<Properties> propertiesList = new ArrayList<Properties>();
String keyToDelete = "blah";

for(Properties p : propertiesList) {
    if(p.getKey().equals(keyToDelete)) {
        propertiesList.remove(index) //How to remove the element at index 'p'
    }
}
```

This is how i would accomplish this with the other `for` loop

```
List<Properties> propertiesList = new ArrayList<Properties>();
String keyToDelete = "blah";

for(int i = 0; i < propertiesList.size(); i++) {
        if(p.getKey().equals(keyToDelete)) {
                propertiesList.remove(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: Your second version is actually wrong. Removing an elements shifts the indices of the elements after it, so you will skip over every element that comes after an element you want to remove.

Comment: One thing that no one seems to be touching on: wouldn't what you're trying to do cause a ConcurrentModificationException if we used the for-each loop? (Even if it doesn't, you have to deal with how elements in the list are shifting, as @TomAnderson pointed out.)

Comment: Looks like a `Map` would be better here.

Comment: Also note that the second solution will be O(N^2) for List implementations that don't implement RandomAccess. This could cause a performance problem with a large LinkedList.

Comment: @SeanReilly: Given that deleting something from an array is O(N), it's also O(N^2) for some lists, like `ArrayList`, that do implement `RandomAccess`!

Comment: Fixing the 2nd version is simple enough though; just iterate last element to first.  BTDT.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I had a map first, but jsf datatable doesn't support Map so i was having to keep a copy of both a map and a list. See my other question regarding that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550354/how-to-access-map-key-in-jsf-datatable/11551934#11551934.

Comment: @TomAnderson Oh man, you're right! ArrayList for the loss.

Comment: Just in case anyone reading this in the future cares, the solution with a worst case of O(N) regardless of the List implementation is to iterate through the list, and add only the elements that you want to keep to a second list.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline iterating backwards is still O(N^2) for ArrayList — N possible removes at O(N) apiece. Imagine a large ArrayList where every second element needs to be removed.

Comment: @SeanReilly Yes, you're right. Brain fade. I am a moron. (But two indexes would work (in O(n), not for `LinkedList`).)

Comment: @SeanReilly Can you guarantee that adding an element to a list is always O(1)?  It seems to be a reasonable assumption; but O() has to include pathological cases too.

Comment: @DanNeely For LinkedList, adding an element is O(1). For ArrayList, adding an element is amortized O(1). I'm sure that you could deliberately create a List implementation that was worse, but you'd be doing it on purpose.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The way to do this is with an explicit [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) (no school like the old school!).

```
Iterator<Properties> it = propertiesList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().getKey().equals(keyToDelete)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Unlike the remove method on a list, the [`remove` method on the iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) doesn't cause a concurrent modification. It's the only safe way to remove an element from a collection you're iterating over. As the javadoc for that method says:

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

Comment: +1 for mentioning concurrent modification. Most of the other answers don't handle the modification case properly — they either risk a ConcurrentModificationException, or there are bugs wrt incrementing the counter.

Comment: As a caveat though, not all Iterators support a remove() operation. (I'm pretty sure it's fine for ArrayList, but it's still something to keep in mind.)

Answer (score 8):

No, you need to use the old-school for loop to get an index.

You could of course add it yourself to the for-each loop, but then you would most probably be better off using the old variant instead.

Comment: Or you can define an index outside of the for-each loop, and increment and use it inside.

Comment: Couldnt you use some kind of iterator as well?

Comment: If i would have to use an external counter, i might as well just switch to the old for loop.

Comment: @MartinLarsson: Sure, you could use an `Iterator` explicitly instead of letting for-each hide it if you need the reference.

Comment: He still won't be able to do what he has in the original, you aren't allowed to remove inside a for-each loop.

Comment: @NominSim Not true. You can always call `remove` on the current iterator.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak His original version is calling remove on the list, meaning it will give a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Of course he could switch it to use an explicit iterator, but this answer doesn't address that issue and implies that it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 8):

How about using proper [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and its `remove` method?

```
List<Properties> propertiesList = new ArrayList<Properties>();
String keyToDelete = "blah";

for (
    Iterator<Properties> iter = propertiesList.iterator( );
    iter.hasNext( );
)
{
    Properties p = iter.next( );

    if(p.getKey().equals(keyToDelete)) {
        iter.remove( );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using Iterator in a `for` loop (better) rather than a `while` (not as good)

Comment: @SteveKuo I disagree - the first argument here in the `for` is so long that it obscures understanding the line at a glance.

Comment: @Izkata. Now that it's split on separate lines, is it better.  One clear advantage is that `iter` variable is contained inside the `for` loop scope.  With `while` it is escaped into the method's scope.

Answer (score 2):

As Tim Anderson suggested you could also modify the list outside the loop

```
List<Properties> propertiesList = new ArrayList<Properties>();
String keyToDelete = "blah";
List<Properties> propertiesToRemove = new ArrayList<Properties>();


for(Properties p : propertiesList) {
    if(p.getKey().equals(keyToDelete)) {
        propertiesToRemove.add(p) ;
    }
}

propertiesList.removeAll(propertiesToRemove);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, foreach loop does not guarantee the order of elements it enumerates,

so if you will try Collection[i] you can get another element rather than currently iterated

It is can be clearly viewed in some multithreaded cases