# Display key and value Map in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dictionary

In my Java EE 6 / JSF 2 project I have a `Map` property `advantages` in the `Employee` entity:

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<String, Float> advantages;
```

The key represents the advantage name and the value represents the cost associated with the advantage name. This is mapped to a table with three columns `Employee_Id`, `Advantages` and `Advantages_Key`. I need to display all map entries in my `<p:dataTable>` which shows a `List<Employee>`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using EL 2.2? [It's supposed to be possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551934/1199132) to iterate a `Collection` directly.

Comment: @XtremeBiker thanks for answer. It's not the same case. I used a datatable to display all Employees Details (name, phone, salary, etc) and I specify tow columns per row to display the AdvantageName (Kye of the Map) and his cost (the value) associated to every emlpoyee.

Comment: I think he means 'to get' .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Provided that your environment supports EL 2.2 (Java EE 6 does), and that `#{employee}` in the below example is coming from `<p:dataTable var>`, then this should do

```
<ui:repeat value="#{employee.advantages.entrySet().toArray()}" var="entry">
    Name: #{entry.key}, Cost: #{entry.value}
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 7):

this works for me, and this is my map in bean Map:

```
<p:dataTable id="dtbAddedRoles" value="#{controllerUserCreationMain.mapUtil.entrySet().toArray()}"
                                var="roleAdded">
                                <p:column headerText="Role">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{roleAdded.key.roleName}" />
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Works also without `.toArray()` for me (Primefaces 6.1).

Answer (score 0):

I know that answer is too late, but maybe for others it will be useful.

Assume your haspmap is defined as follows:

```
HashMap<String, BigDecimal> myHashMap;

public List<Entry<String, BigDecimal>> getMyHashMapEntryList() {
return new ArrayList(myHashMap.entrySet());
}
```

in your UI:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{yourBean.myHashMapEntryList}" var="myEntry">
    in here reference as: #{myEntry.key} #{myEntry.value}
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: The getter method is called during every iteration round of `<p:dataTable>`. The `ArrayList` constructor itself also iterates over every item of the passed-in collection. In other words, this piece of code is terribly inefficient.

Comment: you can easily make method to return single instance if you care about efficient. here is just an example