# Linked Hash Map EL for key and value in primefaces 5

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

My below code is working fine with primefaces 3.4.2 and JSF 2.1.10, after upgrading it to primefaces 5 and 2.1.27 the key and value of hashmap is throwing following error
**The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'key'.**

How to access the key and value of hashmap in below code?

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="bldgGISTypeCode" value="#{buildingBean.originalBuilding.gisTypeCode}" styleClass="#{buildingBean.validationResults[8] eq false? 'ui-inputtext-border-color-red':''}" style="width:65%">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
<f:selectItems value="#{buildingBean.originalBuilding.gisTypeList}" var="gis" itemLabel="#{gis.key}" itemValue="#{gis.value}"/>  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Check this posts: [how to access map key in jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550354/how-to-access-map-key-in-jsf-datatable) [Our selectOneMenu wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) [jsf-2-fselectitems-with-map-does-not-display-itemlabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655349/jsf-2-fselectitems-with-map-does-not-display-itemlabel/10656919#10656919)